# Is there a way to use <Collapse> as my Transition component while using the <Popper> component to display a Menu onHover?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The following question is regarding React and Material-UI:

I am trying to use the `<Collapse>` transition component when displaying my `<Menu>` onMouseEnter. However, there seems to be an issue in the Material-UI library when it comes to the way the `<Collapse>` component and the `<Popper>` / `<Popover>` component. The issue is currently open and can be seen [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11337).

Has anyone found a good workaround for this? Basically, I am just hoping to have a subnav Menu appear when you hover over a link with this specific transition.

I have tried using the `<Grow>` component and the transition works just fine, but we specifically are trying to use the `<Collapse>` transition.

```
export const NavBarItem = ({ navItem }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const anchorRef = React.useRef(null);

  function handleToggle() {
    setOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen);
  }

  function handleClose(event) {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }

    setOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Link className={classes.link} href={BASE_HOMEPAGE + navItem.path}>
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          ref={anchorRef}
          aria-controls="menu-list-grow"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onMouseEnter={handleToggle}
          onMouseLeave={handleToggle}
        >
          {navItem.title}
        </Typography>
      </Link>
      <Popper
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
        onMouseEnter={handleToggle}
        onMouseLeave={handleToggle}
        transition
        disablePortal
        placement="bottom-start"
      >
        <Collapse in={open}>
            <Paper id="menu-list-grow">
              <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
                <MenuList className={classes.paperMenu}>
                  {navItem.menuItems.map(item => (
                    <Link
                      className={classes.link}
                      href={
                        item.external ? item.path : BASE_HOMEPAGE + item.path
                      }
                    >
                      <MenuItem
                        className={classes.paperMenuItem}
                        onClick={handleClose}
                      >
                        {item.text}
                      </MenuItem>
                    </Link>
                  ))}
                </MenuList>
              </ClickAwayListener>
            </Paper>
            </Collapse>
      </Popper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

The code shown above is for a specific NavItem in a NavComponent. It is essentially just a dropdown component to show a subnav when you hover over a specific link.

Thank you for your help and please let me know if you need anymore additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `TransitionProps` given by the `Popper` when using the `transition` props, as shown in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/#transitions)

```
<Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
  {({ TransitionProps }) => (
    <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
      <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
    </Fade>
  )}
</Popper>
```

For smoother UI you can also use the `keepMounted` property in `Popper`:

```
<Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition keepMounted>
```

Comment: The OP is specifically asking about the Collapse Transition which even when using TransitionProps as shown in the documentation does not work the same as the Grow or Fade transition.